# Load chrome's home page from the keyboard on a chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, shortcuts, chromebook

Running a chromebook there seems to be no way to load the browser's, Google chrome, home page from the keyboard.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a alt+home keyboard equivalent, I know ctrl+l then typing say google.com will do, but I miss the alt+home quickness

Answer (score 0):

alt-shift-t moves the focus to the navigation buttons, from there you can tab-tab to the Home button (assuming your home button is set to [show](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en)).